# What is ReOptimizeTNLP() function in IPOPT C++ interface and how to use it?

Tags: c++, optimization, nlp, nonlinear-optimization, ipopt

I am using IPOPT to solve my MPC and try to speed it up. I have turned on the warm start and got a significant improvement. However, I found that there is a function handle called ReOptimizeTNLP(), but it is not mentioned in the C++ interface documentation. I found that some third-party code uses this function starting from the second optimization. I checked the code a bit and found that this method reuses TNLPAdapter. In actual use, it seems that using ReOptimizeTNLP() will make the number of iterations after the warm start more stable and keep smaller. What is the difference between ReOptimizeTNLP() and OptimizeTNLP()? How is it different from directly enabling the warm start? When or under what conditions can it be used? Thank you very much!

Comment: I got the answer at https://github.com/coin-or/Ipopt/discussions/499. Thanks Stefan.